# Appcenter distribute in-app updates not working in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to distribute an internal iOS app (built using Xamarin.iOS) using Visual Studio AppCenter, but can't seem to get in-app updates to work.

when I download and install the app (through the email link) the browser never opens to register for in-app updates, and when I distribute a new release to that group, the app does not offer an update.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin).

I've added the info.plist entries and started the appcenter distribute module. Analytics + Crash reporting are working OK so the AppCenter ID is fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create your own VersionChecker, in the override of the ViewDidLoad of the first view controller, you can call the CheckVersion() function

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{        
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    CheckVersion();
    OtherCode();
}
```

And then in the CheckVersion function you could do something like this

```
        public async void CheckVersion()
        {
            var newVersionAsString = new VersionObject();
            string responseContent = string.Empty;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var versionCheckUri = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/saamerm/af01aec0187d38a22fdd9b4378afc9c3/raw/680332a9a45eb015bc17fbf817fbac537348e3d4/Version.json"
                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(versionCheckUri))
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            newVersionAsString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VersionObject>(responseContent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }

            var currentVersion = new Version(NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"].ToString());

            if (currentVersion != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newVersionAsString) && (new Version(newVersionAsString.latestVersion)) > currentVersion)
            {
                string AppleStoreAppUrl = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/{YOURAPPURL}?mt=8";
                var alert = new AlertView { ViewController = this, Title = "Update Required", Message = "To continue using this mobile app, please install the latest version." };
                alert.AddAction("Update Now", ActionStyle.Cancel, (action) => { UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(AppleStoreAppUrl)); this.Dispose(); }).Show();
            }
```

where VersionObject we got from jsonutils.com

```
 public class VersionObject
    {
        public string latestVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

Please test this before using it, I can see an instance where it may not work

Comment: Thanks @saamer. I will test it before using it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @saamer, I have tried the above code and tested it, I am able to get the latest version but when I want to download it the url needs be of appcenter not the App Store (since the app is not in App Store). Any idea about the app url in appcenter.?

Comment: Hmm yeah what's your appcenter URL when you access it from the iPhone?

Comment: Hi Saamer, The app center url from the phone shows as https://install.appcenter.ms/users/lavanya.naredla/apps/Sample/releases/5?source=email. Not sure whether it works or not :)

Comment: What about the App Center URL of the app? Maybe you haven't placed the apps inside an organization

Comment: One question @saamer, Right now I have my apps in hockey app, and I am trying to transit to app center, Can I use url "https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/appid" even after hockey app retire?                                                                                                 Yeah you are right, I did not placed my apps in organization.

Comment: You ll be able to for a little bit, but they ll get rid of it completely. Place your apps in an organization and then access the app from there. That way testers who visit that page, will be directed to download the iOS app in a few clicks

Comment: @lavanya any success on this?

Comment: Hi @saamer,  when I gave the download url from iPhone like https://install.appcenter.ms/org/yourorganizationname/apps/appname/distribution_groups/distributiongroupname, it says cannot connect to install.appcenter.ms.

Comment: The ur  is not working when i try to install it from Xamarin.ios app only. When I try to open the url from safari browser it downloads the app

Comment: Yes, you have to tell the app to open the url in the browser

Comment: The entire download url I gave looks like itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://install.appcenter.ms/org/yourorganizationname/apps/appname/distribution_groups/distributiongroupname. It should work right?

Comment: itms-services:// opens the App Store on your phone, and since your app on AppCenter, is not going to be visible/available through there, you just have to use string AppCenterUrl = "install.appcenter.ms/org/yourorganizationname/apps/appname/…" instead and remove the whole itms-services:// stuff

Comment: What if I don't want to open the appcenter page and directly wants to install the version into phone. My client will not be liking to visit the appcenter from our app and install it. Right now using HockeyApp I gave the url like itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/appid and it directly starts installing the app into the phone without me taking to the HockeyApp version page

Comment: Hmm, you cant do that with the MS App Center. But ignoring the certification issues that you might face, for that you will have to manually upload your builds to a website like dropbox or google drive and just put in the public link to the build. Perhaps you could extend your Github Gist to have the URL to the build as well and then just open that link instead

Comment: Hmm yeah right. Thank you for all your support and responses.Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

@lavanya there could be a lot of different reasons as to why they are not working. As you can see in the Notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/inappupdates) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin),

1. Did your testers download the app from the default safari browser?
2. Are cookies enabled for Safari in their settings?
3. Is your app not available in the App Store yet?

Could you please provide more details? Because if you answered No to any of those questions, you won't be able to use MS App Center's In App Updates on iOS

Comment: Thank you for the reply.                                                                             1. Did your testers download the app from the default safari browser? Yes, we downloaded the app from the email we get once its distributed from the appcenter
2. Are cookies enabled for Safari in their settings? Yes
3. Is your app not available in the App Store yet? Yes.

Comment: So first I coded the app as per the doc and uploaded version (1.0) and distributed it. Installed it in iPhone from the Email. So to test in app update, I have uploaded another version (1.1) . So now when i open 1.0 version app its not prompting any update version dialog. Not sure what's going on. Please help me out. Thank you inadvance.

Comment: @lavanya Im so sorry for what you're facing. Why don't you just create a simple Gist JSON file containing a Version so the app can check that every time you load the app

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea but I am not sure how our app can compare the versions. Any idea on like how to access the property list file of the latest version in the appcenter?. That way I can get the version info of the latest version and then can compare it with current app bundle version

Comment: The code in AppDelegate FinishedLaunching             Distribute.SetEnabledAsync(true);
                Distribute.DontCheckForUpdatesInDebug();
                Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable; // Custom dialog
                bool enabled = Distribute.IsEnabledAsync().Result;
                AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;
                AppCenter.Start("app secret", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
               Let me know if I have done anything wrong in the coding

Comment: You create a rest call for the raw version of a gist like this https://gist.githubusercontent.com/saamerm/af01aec0187d38a22fdd9b4378afc9c3/raw/680332a9a45eb015bc17fbf817fbac537348e3d4/Version.json . You can use https://jsonutils.com to create the Model class. Doing a JSON serialize, you will get current version. Place a check so that every time the user gets on the Home page, if they don't have the current version of the app, it Displays the Alert. And when they tap on it, you can direct them to the Website where they can download the right version

Comment: Check the other Answer I posted